# Determine whether a subspace of Hilbert space is closed or not?

Tags: integration, limits

Let $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ be the usual Sobolev space consisting of $L^2$ functions on $\mathbb{R}$ whose weak derivatives are also in $L^2$.Define  $$
E=\left\{u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}): \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigl[|\dot u(t)|^2+(t^2+1)u^2(t)\Bigr]dt<+\infty\right\},
$$
then $E$ is a Hilbert space with the inner product
$$
(u,v)_E=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dot u(t)\dot v(t)+(t^2+1)u(t)v(t)dt
$$
and the corresponding norm $\|u\|^2=(u,u)_E$.

It is well-known that $E\subset C^0(\mathbb{R})$ , the space of continuous functions $u$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $u(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $|t|\rightarrow +\infty$.

Next, we define a subspace $E_0$ of $E$ as follows:

$$
E_0=\left\{u\in E:\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t^2+1)^2u^2(t)dt<+\infty\right\}. 
$$

Now, the question is to ask  **whether  $E_0$ is a closed subspace of $E$?** More precisely, if $u_n\in E_0$ with $u_n\rightarrow u_0$ in $E$, i.e., 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t^2+1)^2u_n^2(t)dt<+\infty, \forall n
$$ 
and 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigl[|\dot u_n(t)-\dot u_0(t)|^2+(t^2+1)(u(t)-u_0t))^2\Bigr]dt\rightarrow 0, \quad \text{as } n \rightarrow \infty,
$$
then can we infer that $u_0\in E_0$ or 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t^2+1)^2u_0^2(t)dt<+\infty ? 
$$
The difficulty is how to show the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}t^4u_0^2(t)dt<+\infty $? 
A simple observation: If we want to disprove the question, then we need to construct a sequence $u_n\in E$ converging to $u_0\in E\setminus E_0$ with
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t^2+1)^2u_n^2(t)dt=+\infty. 
$$
Otherwise, by the embedding above,  we would have from Fatou's lemma that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t^2+1)^2u_0^2(t)dt\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(t^2+1)^2u_n^2(t)dt<+\infty, 
$$
showing $u_0\in E_0$, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 1):

After many trials with Mathematica, I found an example to disprove the posed question above. Specifically, let $u_n(t)=1/(t^2+1+t^3/n)$ and let $u_0(t)=1/(1+t^2)$. Then one has $u_n\in E_0$ and $u_0\not\in E$. My computations show that $\|u_n-u_0\|_E\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Hence, the question is disproved.